# Не могу подключить System.Threading

Tags: c#

Всем привет !
Буду признателен, если поможете разобраться в следующей ситуации:
Не могу подключить пространство имён Sysnem.Threading.Tasks для работы с потоками. Погуглил, везде пишут что возможная причина версия <4.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас на скриншоте подключено пространство имен System.Threading.Tasks. В чем проблема?

Comment: у вас на скринах ошибок нет

Comment: Они выделены серым цветом и по факту неактивны. Я не могу создать экземпляр класса Thread

Comment: Что вам мешает это сделать? `var thread = new Thread();` ?

Comment: Они серые, т.к. вы не используете в коде ни одного класса из них, и студия подсвечивает их как неактивные / лишние

Comment: @tym32167 нет таких убеждений, которые помешали бы мне сделать это, но всё равно не получается. Добавил скрин.

Comment: Бывает. Иногда помогает рестарт студии. Иногда помогает грохнуть всю папку .vs в проекте. А иногда помогает очистка кеша nuget (и fallback тоже) но то больше для core проектов

Comment: Ситуация аналогична и на рабочем компе.

Comment: на скрине слева лампочка со стрелкой вниз. Нажмите

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое ! )

Comment: @AndreyGrek пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

`Thread` находится в пространстве имен `System.Threading`, а у вас `System.Threading.Tasks` указан.